# PostgreSQL: How to update one field of a table with value of a field of another table random entry

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a addressbook table and a table with a lot of random names (random_names). I want to update my addressbook table name field with the last_name field of my random_names table - RANDOMLY.

I tried.

```
UPDATE addressbook
SET "name"=sub.last_name
FROM (SELECT last_name, random() as rand
    FROM random_names 
    ORDER BY rand) sub
WHERE name <> sub.last_name;
```

This basically works, but I don't really get random names. Sure I'm getting a random name, but each entry is updated with the same single random entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a subquery after the assignment:

```
UPDATE  addressbook as ab
SET     "name" = 
        (
        SELECT  rn.last_name
        FROM    random_names rn
        WHERE   rn.last_name <> ab.last_name
        ORDER BY 
                random()
        LIMIT   1
        )
```

Not sure if Postgres will evaluate the subquery for each row, but can't hurt to try.